# Labels in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am facing a problem in development in MSBI.I have created a bar chart which Contains Year as its X-axis.I want to display a Label with the

Same name as the user click on the chart.

Eg-User clicks on 2008 bar in bar-chart.A message should get displayed that-Data is of …… year.

How do I achieve this in MSBI 2008.Plz tell me any work around for that…!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about reports hosted in SSRS, there is no way to display a message to the user on a mouse click.

Instead, you can display a tooltip when the user hovers the mouse over a bar. To do that, use the `Tooltip` property of the data series.

Comment: No, i am not using report builder.I am using SSRS only.

Comment: Sorry, to be clearer, however you create them, SSRS reports do not support displaying a message when a user clicks on a bar.

Comment: If i make a chart by making use of Report builder then it is possible to achieve my goal....?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know of any way. You can have clickable elements in reports, but they are pretty much limited to expanding/collapsing existing elements, or opening new reports. You could either use always visible labels, or perhaps have the labels popup as tooltips when the users mouse hovers over an element.